# String variable comparison with value failing in php

Tags: php

Here is the array `$item_meta_data` I am working on: 
[image]

And here is the code I have:

```
$found = false;    
foreach( $item_meta_data as $key => $meta ){
                if( $meta['name'] == "Hardware" && $meta['display'] == "Free-Standing Hardware (max height = 14')" ) {
                    $found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

The `$meta['display'] == "Free-Standing Hardware (max height = 14')"` is unexpectedly failing...I used double quotes to wrap the value because there's a single quote in the value. I have also checked the value is string:
[image]

Can anyone point out if there's something wrong with the `if` statement? Interestingly, everything works if array has a simpler value in `$meta['display']`

PS: I have also tried the triple === comparative `$meta['display'] === "Free-Standing Hardware (max height = 14')"` with no effect

Comment: instead of "==", can you try this with strcmp() function?

Comment: try to print $meta['display'] value here

Comment: Any chance that there's extra whitespace or non-visible characters in the string?  Or that something like the hyphen or single-quote are only visually similar but aren't exactly a hyphen or single-quote but some other character?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar tried the strcmp() to no avail. I have already printed the value of $meta['display'] in the same image where the type is shown.

Comment: @David I am also thinking the same thing, any idea how to be sure that's not happening? Interestingly, I copy pasted the value from the website back-end and still the comparison is failing.

Comment: @DanishMuneer: As a debugging step you could try converting both strings to byte arrays and outputting the byte values side-by-side to see in what way the values are not binary-equivalent.

Comment: Using double equals is rarely a good idea

Comment: Why don't you try your code, keeping everything as it is but removing the single quote after the word "height" and add a word there. I mean try something like Free-Standing Hardware (max height = 14 feet) and check.

Comment: I'm trying your same code it's working for me.   <?php

$found = false;    
$item_meta_data = array(array("name"=>"Hardware", "display"=>"Free-Standing Hardware (max height = 14')"), array("name"=>"Hardware1", "display"=>"Free-Standing Hardware1 (max height = 14')"));
foreach( $item_meta_data as $meta ){
                if($meta['name'] == "Hardware" && $meta['display'] == "Free-Standing Hardware (max height = 14')" ) {
                    $found = true;
     echo 'match';
                    break;
                }
            }
   
   
   ?>

Comment: your code is working. . maybe some whitespace  is coming in your case. use trim function and check

Comment: @David byte check returns same value for both

Comment: @JitendraAhuja thank you. when I replaced the single quote with ft, (max height = 14ft) the code started to work. however I need to use the single quote in the value ...I tried using the backslash \ before the single quote but didn't work ..any other ideas?

Comment: @ShivendraSingh yes I tried the same on phptester site and it was working ... I think the single quote is the issue.

Comment: After comparing two strings for hashing? E.g. md5()

Comment: @Luna returns the same...I will try converting the single quote to hex value to see if it gives some indication

Comment: Your `'` inside the data might not actually be a `'`, but rather an HTML entity such as `&apos;` or the numeric equivalent. If you look at your debug output directly in the browser, which is interpreting it as HTML, you will of course not see the difference - so check the HTML source code your browser received instead. Also, get in the habit of using var_dump instead of print_r for such debug outputs - var_dump also shows you the _length_ of the variable content, which makes it easier to spot such situations.

Comment: @04FS thanks, this is exactly what I suspect but I am going to get rid of the single quote altogether now to resolve this.